# How to input a "-" between repeating characters in a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion to loop through the String array and input a "-" between repeating characters. Ex: "hello" would output to "hel-lo"

This is my code so far:

Main Class:
public class L6C13PairStar {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PairStar str = new PairStar();
    str.callStars();
}
```

}

PairStar class:

```
public class PairStar {

    private String[] strs={"hello","xxaayybbzz","aabbaaccdef","jiladdsqss","g","","allstars"};

    public void callStars()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<strs.length; i++)
            System.out.println(stars(strs[i]));
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
    }

    public String stars(String str)
    {
        String temp = null;
        if (str.length() > 1)
            temp=stars(str.substring(1,str.length()));
        if (temp == null && str.length() > 1)
            temp=str.substring(1);
        if (temp != null)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
            {
                int num = 0;
                int num1 = 1;

                if (str.charAt(num)==str.charAt(num1))
                {

                    str = str.charAt(num) + "-" +str.charAt(num1)+temp; 
                    num++;
                    num1++;
                }
            }
            return str;
        }  
        return str;
    }
}
```

And outputs to:

```
hello,
x-xxaayybbzz,
a-aabbaaccdef,
jiladdsqss,
g,
 ,
allstars
*******************************************
```

The code only checks if the first two characters are the same. How to I make it continue looking through each part of the array?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) Use a `StringBuilder` to accumulate your string. 2) Append the first character of your input to the `StringBuilder`. 3) for all other characters in the string, check if the current character it is equal to the preceding character: if it is, append a `-`; then, always, append the current character.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sounds like a good *answer* to me.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't want to spoon-feed OP. But sure, have an answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner I just meant, write the comment as an answer, without adding code. Let OP write the code from the guidance of what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a `StringBuilder` to accumulate your string.
2. Append the first character of your input to the `StringBuilder`.
3. For all other characters in the string:

   1. Check if the current character it is equal to the preceding character: if it is, append a `-`;
   2. Then, always, append the current character.

I'll let you work out the code for yourself (if you didn't see it in my previous answer...)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Since I'm using recursion it made the output repeat itself a few times but your answer helped me a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the given string array, put each string into a char array using `toCharArray()` and check for repeating characters ad use a `StringBuilder` to insert `-` character:

```
    String[] strs = {"hello", "xxaayybbzz", "aabbaaccdef",
        "jiladdsqss", "g", "", "allstars"};
    for (int j = 0; j < strs.length; j++) {
        String str = strs[j];
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            builder.append(chars[i]);
            if (i < chars.length - 1 && chars[i] == chars[i + 1]) {
                builder.append('-');
            }
        }
        strs[j] = builder.toString();
    }

    for (String s : strs) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
hel-lo
x-xa-ay-yb-bz-z
a-ab-ba-ac-cdef
jilad-dsqs-s
g

al-lstars
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Stringbuilder as someone else said, get the values from the array and use Stringbuilder to do the dirty work for you. If you need the values in the array you can always save the values back (overwrite) the values in the array if oldValue != newValue.